# How to implement Twilio Vue.js Tutorial

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, twilio

I try to follow the this Twilio Tutorial:
https://www.twilio.com/blog/create-video-conference-app-laravel-php-vue-js

As it is based on Laravel 6 I encounter some errors following in 2022.
I already fixed route by adding the full namespace of the AccessTokenController

However in the tutorial I get asked to "Replace the code in welcome.blade.php with the following:"

```
...
<script>
export default {
    name: 'video-chat',
    data: function () {
        return {
            accessToken: ''
        }
    },
    methods : {
        getAccessToken : function () {

            const _this = this
            const axios = require('axios')
            
            // Request a new token
            axios.get('/api/access_token')
                .then(function (response) {
                    _this.accessToken = response.data
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                })
                .then(function () {
                    console.log( _this.accessToken )
                });
        }
    },
    mounted : function () {
        console.log('Video chat room loading...')

        this.getAccessToken()
    }
}
</script>
```

However I think the author made a mistake and actually meant the VideoChat.vue file content.

But the pasted code does not work. I don't even get a console log. As I am novice to vue.js I would like to ask the community what the error might be.

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right, that the code you have pasted should go into `VideoChat.vue`.

In `welcome.blade.php` make sure you have replaced the `<example-component></example-component>` with `<video-chat></video-chat>`. Then you should see some logs in your console and the application fetch the access token.